# Use current row by referencing to cell

Tags: excel, reference, cell

I am trying to have a text in excel with a variable value that is based on a cell from the current row. I have this to reference to a different cell and load the data as a variable:

```
 ="This will display the value of column A and row 2: " & $A$2
```

I want to have the value of the cell that is located in column A in the same row as from where I am referencing.

How can I do that?

Kind regards,
Gust de Backer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $ signs lock the reference to the specified column and/or row. Remove the $ sign to make the row number relative.

When you enter the formula in row 2, use the reference `$A2`. Note that there is no $ sign in front of the `2`. This is called a relative reference. When this formula is copied down, the reference will change. Copied to row 3, it will show `$A3`, in row 4 it will be `$A4` and so on.